# Binomial coefficients and "missing primes"

Tags: nt.number-theory

Define the following two subsets of prime numbers
$$\Pi_n:=\{p: \text{$p$ is prime, $p\leq n$}\}$$
and
$$B_n:=\{p: \text{$p$ is prime, $p$ divides $\binom{n}k$ for some $0< k< n$}\}.$$
Denote their respective cardinalities by $\pi(n):=\vert\Pi_n\vert$ and $\,b(n):=\vert B_n\vert$.

> **QUESTIONS.** Experimental evidence suggest that
>
> (a) $\pi(n)-b(n)=0$ or $1$.
>
> (b) If $\pi(n)-b(n)=1$, then the missing prime is the largest prime divisor of $n+1$.
>
> Are these true statements?

Comment: Presumably Lucas's theorem is relevant here?: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas's_theorem

Comment: I'm aware of this valuable theorem, although it did not help. Perhaps it does, not sure.

Comment: It should be clear that the only primes that could be missing are those dividing n+1.  Also, if there is a power of p less than n but bigger than n/2 with p dividing n then p is not missing.  I think Lucas's theorem is useful. I think a and b are plausible and that the proofs will be easy.  Gerhard "Is Not Proving Them Now" Paseman, 2016.11.17.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: like most number theory problems, either these are too easy or notoriously hard. I await the verdict.

Comment: The solutions given already cover a.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose that $p $ is a prime satisfying $p\le n$ and $p\nmid \binom{n}{k}$ for all $k=1,\ldots,n-1.$ Then from [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) it follows that the base-$p$ representation of $n$ is $n=(a,p-1,\ldots,p-1)_p$ with $1\le a\le p-1$. So $n=(a+1)p^r-1$, where $r$ is the number of base-$p$ digits in $n$. Then $n+1 = (a+1)p^r$ with $a+1 \leq p$, so any prime factor of $n+1$ besides $p$ is a prime factor of $a+1$, so it has to be less than $p$.

Here is a second solution, using [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas's_theorem): writing $n = n_0+n_1p+\cdots +n_rp^r$, where $0 \leq n_i \leq p-1$ and $n_r \geq 1$, 
each $k$ in $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ has base-$p$ representation $k_0+k_1p+\cdots +k_rp^r$ where $0 \leq k_i \leq p-1$ (maybe $k_r = 0$ if $k$ is much smaller than $n$). Then Lucas' theorem says
$$
\binom{n}{k} \equiv \binom{n_0}{k_0}\binom{n_1}{k_1}\cdots \binom{n_r}{k_r} \bmod p.
$$
For digits $n_i$ and $k_i$, which are in $\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$, we have $\binom{n_i}{k_i} \equiv 0 \bmod p$ if and only if $n_i < k_i$ (otherwise the factors in $\binom{n_i}{k_i} = \frac{n_i(n_i-1)\cdots(n_i-(k_i-1))}{k_i!}$ are all nonzero modulo $p$).  Thus we have $\binom{n}{k} \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$ for *all* $k$ from $0$ to $n$ (let's allow $k=0$ and $k=n$ since those cases are not divisible by $p$) if and only if every $k \leq n$ has $k_i \leq n_i$ for $i < r$ and $k_r \leq n_r$, and that's equivalent to $n_i = p-1$ for $i < r$ (if some $n_i < p-1$ then at $k = (p-1)p^i$ we have $\binom{n}{k} \equiv 0 \bmod p$). Such $n$ have the form $(p-1)+(p-1)p\cdots+(p-1)p^{r-1} + n_rp^r = (n_r+1)p^r-1$. If $r = 0$ then $n = n_r \leq p-1$. If $r \geq 1$ then $p \mid (n+1)$, and the first solution shows easily in this case why $p$ has to be the largest prime factor of $n+1$. In summary, every prime that is $\leq n$ divides some $\binom{n}{k}$ for $1 \leq k \leq n-1$ except when $n = mp^r-1$ where $r \geq 1$, $p$ is prime, and $2 \leq m \leq p$, in which case the prime $p$ divides no $\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: After $n=(a+1)p^k-1$ we may just say 'and so $p$ is indeed the largest prime divisor of $n+1$'.

Comment: @Fedor Petrov Yes, thank you! It gives shorter solution.

Comment: "...Kummer's theorem follows that base-$p$ representation of $n$ is $n=(a,p-1,\dots,p-1)_p$..." What is the justification?

Comment: @T. Amdeberhan Suppose that one of the (non-leading) digits of number $n$ is less than $p-1$. Then you can find $k$ such that the number of carries when $k$ is added to $n − k$ in base p will be at least $1$. For $n=(1344)_5$ number $k$ must have the form $(4**)_5$. For $n=(1444)_5$ there are no such $k$'s.

Answer (score 13):

I like the following argument.

Let $p \leq n$ be a missing prime.  Then $p \leq  n/2$ as otherwise $p $ divides $\binom{n}{n+1-p}$. Also $p$ divides $n+1$ as $p$ does not divide $\binom{n}{k}$ for $0\leq k \leq p$. Similarly $p^b$
must divide $n+1$ for all $b$ up to the highest power of $p \lt n$, otherwise there is a $k\lt p^b$ (or $k \leq n/2$) which reveals $p$. So $n+1 = cp^b$ for some $c\lt p$. So both conditions hold, and the latter can be strengthened to apply only with $n=cp^b - 1$.

Gerhard "Likes Writing  Low Power Arguments" Paseman, 2016.11.17.

Comment: "Also $p$ divides $n+1$ as $p$ does not divide $\binom{n}k$..." Why?

Comment: For $2p \leq n$, one of $n,n-1,\ldots,n+1-p$ is a multiple of $p$. If $p$ is hidden, it must be $n+1-p$.  Something similar applies to $p^b\leq n/2$; a different argument works for $n/2 \lt p^b \leq n$. Gerhard "Leaving Some Fun For You" Paseman, 2016.11.18.